# php quiz script which is using checbox and retrieving values from database dynamically

Tags: php, mysql

i have a problem with quiz script where i am trying to do the quiz with checkbox. but the answer is working only for the first checkbox where i am trying to check answer fro each input type checkbox. here is the code i am working with -

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="css/lessframwork.css"/>
<title>Model Test & Quiz</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

<h2>Result Details:</h2>
<?php
include ("connection.php");

@$Test_Title_ID = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Test_Title_ID']);
//echo $Test_Title_ID.'T';
@$Quiz_Cat_ID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Quiz_Cat_ID']);
//echo $Quiz_Cat_ID.'C';
$php_self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$display = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE Test_Title_ID='$Test_Title_ID' ORDER BY Quiz_ID");
if (!@$_POST['submit']) {

echo "<form method=post action='$php_self'>";
echo "<table border=0>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($display)) {

$Quiz_ID = $row["Quiz_ID"];
$question = $row["question"];
$opt1 = $row["opt1"];
$opt2 = $row["opt2"];
$opt3 = $row["opt3"];
$answer = $row["answer"];
$Test_Title_ID = $row["Test_Title_ID"];

echo "<tr><td colspan=3><br><b>$question</b></td></tr>";

echo "<tr><td>$opt1<input type=checkbox name='q[]' value=\"$opt1\"></td>
<td>$opt2<input type=checkbox name='q[]' value=\"$opt2\"></td>
<td>$opt3<input type=checkbox name='q[]' value=\"$opt3\"></td></tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
if(@$Test_Title_ID!="")
{
echo "<input type='hidden' name='Test_Title_ID' value='$Test_Title_ID'>";
}


echo "<input type='submit' value='See how you did' name='submit'>";
echo "</form>";

}
elseif ($_POST['submit']) {
$Test_Title_ID = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Test_Title_ID']);
//echo 'hi'.$Test_Title_ID.'bb';
$display = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quiz WHERE Test_Title_ID='$Test_Title_ID' ORDER BY Quiz_ID");
$score = 0;
$total = mysql_num_rows($display);
//echo $total;

while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($display)) {
$ar=$_POST[q];
//echo $ar;
$arrlength=count($ar);
//echo $arrlength;
for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++)
{
echo $ar[$x];
echo "<br>";
}
$comma_separated = implode(",", $ar);
echo $comma_separated."<br>";
@$answer = $result[answer];
$q = "q$result[Quiz_ID]";
$q = trim($q);
if ($comma_separated == $answer) {
$score++;
}
}

echo "<p align=center><b>You scored $score out of $total</b></p>";
echo "<p>";
}
if ($_POST['submit'])
{
$percentage=$score*100/$total;
if($percentage>=50)
{
echo "You got $percentage% mark. Passed. Get Complete Result <a href='quiz_view.php?Test_Title_ID=$Test_Title_ID'><font color='red'>Here</font></a>";
}
else
{
echo "You got $percentage% mark. Failed. You have to pass to get complete result.";
}
}
mysql_close($connection);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

can anybody help me why the answer isn't checking in loop for every question

Comment: `$ar=$_POST[q];` -> `$ar=$_POST['q'];`

Comment: why do you use so much error suppression? it's not good practice.

Comment: but the problem isn't solved. the loop is checking only the first answer and taking other questions checkbox value. I want to get answer checked with $answer for every question.

Comment: I think the problem is in you way of doing the quiz.
How you have it
Question:
3 answers??
if yest dont use check box use radiobutton with the same name.
So for each question you will have one value of answer that you can compare to DB answer stored.

Comment: @Froxz answer can be 2 or 3, so it must have to be checkbox.. you may have noticed $opt1, $opt2 and $opt3 for each checkbox and saving their values in array. here is the database structure- 
  `Quiz_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Quiz_Cat_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Test_Title_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `question` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `opt1` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `opt2` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `opt3` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `answer` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Quiz_ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=35 ;

Comment: dont implode the answers, use POST array and SQL array/
Run a Loop to compare values in 2 arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is how you're storing the results. For each question, you render checkboxes with `name=q[]`, however, you render three checkboxes of this same `name` for *every* question. This means that the `$_POST["q"]` array will have the values of *every* checkbox on the *page* that was checked, not just the checkboxes that were checked for that particular question you're looping over. Basically you're getting answers per test rather than per question.

For example, say you have:

Question 1: Possible answers: 1,2,3. Right answer: 2,3

Question 2: Possible answers: 1,2,3. Right answer: 1

And the student answers:

Question 1: 2,3

Question 2: 1

Those are the right answers, but the `$comma_separated` variable will be equal to `2,3,1`, and you'll be checking for equality with `2,3` and `1`, so of course there will never be a match.

Thus the result is that the score is only incremented if the student answers exactly one question correctly.

I've provided an annotated source here for anyone who's wondering (with explanations of deprecations that I don't want to get into here): http://pastebin.com/MumuA60M

**EDIT**: The way to get around this is having the names of the checkboxes be dependent on the name of the qustion. For example:

`<input type=checkbox name='$Quiz_ID-q[]'>`

Then

`$id = $results["Quiz_ID"]; $ar=$_POST["$id_q"];`

This is still a little bit of confusing notation, but I think it will work better.

Comment: yes..that's true .. 2,3,1 will come as output but that's not i want. i need 2,3 and 1 as separate answer for question 1 and 2. Implode is taking all value in q[]. I also tried to change the name q[] as $quiz_id.q[] for dynamic checkbox name, but don't know how to use the value in $_POST as it isn't giving me result.

Comment: If you have a series of checkboxes named `1.q[]`, then another series named `2.q[]`, etc, then you should be able to access them in `$_POST["1.q"]`, `$_POST["2.q"]` etc. See the last few lines of the answer.

Comment: it gives syntax error. however, $Quiz_ID-q[] format doesn't give the error, but here still the answer separation for each question problem exists, the main problem i failed to figure out.

Comment: <input type=checkbox name='$Quiz_ID_q[]'>

Comment: Ah yes, it seems you should use `<input type=checkbox name='$Quiz_ID-q[]'>` instead. I'll update the answer.